# Joomla. Infinite loop detected in JError after I moved website on a bluehost server and manually imported sql database for new domain?

Tags: sql, database, joomla, php

I had to move a website on a bluehost server, that  is in the Joomla Platform 1.7.  I did alot of reasearch  on Joomla.org and google and still haven't resloved  the issue. 
    I recieve the following error: Infinite loop  detected in JError.  I went threw the configuration  file and made sure that database and user match up  with my new database parameters match up and I am still recieving  this issue.  Thank you. Urgent response will be very helpful.  Currently working on this and this  is not a good start.  :(

Comment: Problem in major case should be he password for your database..Please check again !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have ran into the same issue moving my Joomla site from one server to another.  What I learned is the following;

Make sure you look at the parameters in configuration.php. Double check if the following  variables in your configuration.php file is correct. (Double Check) You did mention that you already have done so. In that case I am 98% sure that you have an issue dealing with file Attributes with configuration.php.   Change the **Attributes** of configuration.php from **444** to  ***666.***

To get detailed information about the error, open  the error.php file located in  /libraries/joomla/error/ on your server.

In the  following code:

```
public static function throwError(&$exception)
{
static $thrown = false;
 // If thrown is hit again, we've come back to  JError in the middle of    
  throwing
 another JError, so die!
 if ($thrown) {
// echo debug_print_backtrace();
jexit(JText::_('JLIB_ERROR_INFINITE_LOOP'));
}
```

change the line  **// echo debug_print_backtrace();**

to the following:

```
**print"<pre>";
  echo debug_print_backtrace();
print"</pre>";**
```

Remember- When you change the parameters in configuration.php to you new  database make sure you that configuration.php file attribute is set to 666, Otherwise when you go to save the file it will not change. Try this first..   Good  luck.

Comment: this 444 to 666 is not cleat to me. Would you please explain? I am also facing the same problem.